# Confusion about setbuf example of invalid use from man page

Tags: c, linux, stdio

From `man setbuf` on Ubuntu:

> You must make sure that the space that buf points  to  still  exists  by  the  time stream is closed, which also happens at program termination.  For example, the following is invalid:

Invalid sample code from manpage:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    setbuf(stdin, buf);
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it invalid? Local variable `buf` is destroyed after program returns via `return 0;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the `return` is executed, `buf` no longer exists, but program execution continues with the calling of exit handlers and closing of streams. So, when the stream is closed, the buffer does not exist.

Comment: Ok. So I just need to `malloc` some dynamic memory and let it "leaks". :)

Comment: Or you could refrain from returning and instead call `exit`.

Comment: Or just make the buffer `static`.

Comment: You might as well omit the call to `setbuf()` and simply let the standard I/O library do its stuff.  There are many more reasons to call `setvbuf()`; there are few reasons to call `setbuf()`.

Comment: You could also call `fclose(stdout);` in the `main()` — that too would work (though any functions registered with `atexit()` that write to `stdout` would fail to do so).

Comment: Not fail. It would invoke UB.